# Amazon SP API... GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE ... Latest data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

How can I get the latest reporting data for SETTLEMENT? They give previous weekly data not one-day data